# Adding image to custom html field in store front on shopify

Tags: html, shopify, liquid

Im having issue with simply adding an image to the provided custom html field within the shopify store front. Im trying to utalize as much as the theme has to offer, but I am finding a few nuances that I am struggling to find solutions to.

here is what I'm working with.

```
<img src="{{'cj.png' | /assets/cj.png}} />
```

Everything that I have tried shows up as a broken image.
thanks!

Comment: the path to your image is probably incorrect if you are getting a broken image.  Determine the path to your image, try loading in a browser with domain.com/image_path and once you know its working replace the src value with that path, whatever image_path equals.

Comment: So I uploaded the image straight into my assets folder, how would I go about finding the url?  What I think is the domain.com/image_path appears to not be the image path.

Comment: Im not familiar with the exact tool you are using, i would find another image on your site and look at the path there.  It will probably be in the same place or a similar location.  If you have access to the server running your app, i would review the apps folder structure and look for where images are located. Sorry i couldnt be of more help. Hope this gets you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{{ 'cj.png' | asset_folder | img_tag }}
```

This will output full image tag with correct path.

Also you can get the image url. Click on the image in your asset folder in theme files.  It will show the image. Right click and copy image address.

Comment: Hey, Thanks that worked! One issue though, the {{ 'cj.png' | asset_folder | img_tag }} did not work, but using the path did.

Answer (score 0):

I had better luck with this syntax:

`{{ 'image.png' | asset_img_url: '220x' | img_tag }}`

See the `asset_img_url` section of https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/filters/url-filters for more infromation about `asset_img_url`.

Note that like the answer above, this applies to liquid templates.